# NotifyOfProperty change from inside of ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, mvvm, community-toolkit-mvvm

How can I trigger **NotifyOfPropertyChange** by changing property of item inside of **ObservableCollection**?

Currently I am assigning null to **ObservableCollection** and then the original value. However, I don't think this is a proper solution.

```
ObservableCollection<Item> temp = Collection;
Collection = null;
Collection = temp;
```

I have also tried to implement **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface, but it didn't work

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Does `Item` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: I have tried to implement this interface but it didn't react.

Comment: For the best chance of receiving help, post **everything** you tried. Your implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `Item` would be relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` is not enough, you actually have to use it.

See [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-7.0) for an example.

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.  
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName  
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.  
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    private string m_name = "";

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return m_name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (m_name != value)
            {
                m_name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the answer of @rshepp is a perfect point, it is not the whole story.

The `ObservableCollection` class is designed to enable feedback when items are added or removed from the collection. But if one of the items inside collection changes a value, your collection will not notice - unless the contained items implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface *and* you attach to the event handler.

```
public class MotherClass
{
    public MotherClass()
    {
        MonitoredItems = new();

        MonitoredItems.CollectionChanged += MonitoredItems_CollectionChanged;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> MonitoredItems { get; }

    private void MonitoredItems_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OldItems is not null)
        {
            foreach (Item item in e.OldItems)
            {
                //Removed items
                item.PropertyChanged -= MonitoredItem_PropertyChanged;
            }
        }
        else if (e.NewItems is not null)
        {
            foreach (Item item in e.NewItems)
            {
                //Added items
                item.PropertyChanged += MonitoredItem_PropertyChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    private void MonitoredItem_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is not Item sendingItem)
            return;
        Trace.WriteLine($"The {nameof(Item)} object with Name {sendingItem.Name} has a change in its property {e.PropertyName} ");
    }
}
```

Of course, you are free to extend this example MotherClass to MotherClass extending ObservableCollection, if you are able to contain the the sub-property changed event inside the collection.

Note there is no setter for the ObservableCollection to keep the attached event handler intact. The outside code can still use something like `.Clear` or `.ReplaceRange` to set brand new collection values.